# Can't pass the state props, says undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have bee trying to pass the notes data to another component But I don't know why it says undefined.

```
export default App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([
    { key: 1, value: "Hello there what up", title: "Some Title for this" },
    { key: 2, value: "I want to take notes", title: "another for this one" },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={notes}
        renderItem={({ note }) => (
          <View>
            <NoteItem note={note} />
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
export default NoteItem = ({ note }) => {
    <Text>{note.title}</Text>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of you assume that renderItem in Flatlist has a 'note' property inside it. It does not, it is called item. Also you pass notes but you try to deconstruct note? It should be like this:

```
export default App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([
    { key: 1, value: "Hello there what up", title: "Some Title for this" },
    { key: 2, value: "I want to take notes", title: "another for this one" },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={notes}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <NoteItem note={item} />
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: the notes thing was not the issue, I had already fixed it the the item thing was. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax - `({ note })` - means that the `NoteItem` component expects a prop named `note` to be set; however, you're setting the `notes` prop instead.

Try this:

```
<FlatList
   data={notes}
   renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
     <View key={index}>
       <NoteItem note={item} />
     </View>
   )}
/>
```